# Лучше ли будет, если задавать классы элементам с одинаковыми стилями?

Tags: html, css, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

То есть: Если 3 элемента имеют размер шрифта 24px, то можно ли сделать отдельному классу стиль в 24px и присваивать его таким элементам? Так будет более оптимизированнее?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если отдельно этот класс имеет какое-то значение для сайта и будет использоваться отдельно, то можно. А если нет, то можно и без этого стилизовать тексты в пределах разных блоков. Не факт что в будущем они не изменятся и не станут разными, например в среднем блоке.

Comment: То есть правильно делать всем разные стили, кроме очевидных общих классов(title, subtitle)?

Answer (score -1):

Отвечая на вопросы:

> Если 3 элемента имеют размер шрифта 24px, то можно ли сделать
> отдельному классу стиль в 24px и присваивать его таким элементам?

Посмотрите, ниже вам наглядный пример. Есть один общий класс `.item` с набором стилей. Всем элементам мы присваиваем этот класс. Если какому-либо элементу необходимы дополнительные стили, до добавляем этому элементу дополнительный класс.

> Так будет более оптимизированнее?

Таким образом получается сокращение кода CSS, что способствует уменьшению времени ответа сервера. Сервер быстрее дает отклик, а скорость загрузки страницы увеличивается.

```css
.item {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item red"></div>
<div class="item blue"></div>
<div class="item green"></div>
```